# Computing the principal curvatures and directions without making reference to a parametrization

Tags: differential-geometry

Consider, for instance, the catenoid given by $x^2+y^2 = \cosh^2 z$, and suppose that we want to find the principal curvatures and directions at some point $p=(x,y,z)$ of the surface. Of course, we can do this by parametrizing the catenoid as $$(u,v) \mapsto (\cosh u \cos v, \cosh u \sin v, u),$$ and then computing the Gauss map etc.

However, I was wondering if this is possible to do without making reference to a parametrization. Since the catenoid is a level surface $f^{-1}(\{0\})$ of $$ f(x,y,z) = x^2+y^2 -\cosh^2 z, $$
we can find a Gauss map in Cartesian coordinates at the point $p=(x,y,z)$ by computing
$$ N(p) = \frac{\nabla f(p)}{|\nabla f(p)|} = \frac{1}{\cosh^2 z}(x,y,-\cosh z\sinh z). $$
Furthermore, we can also (after a somewhat tedious, but not too difficult computation) see that the differential $\mathrm dN_p$ is given by
$$ \mathrm dN_p = \frac{1}{\cosh^2 z}
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 0\\
-2x\tanh z & -2y\tanh z & -1
\end{pmatrix}. $$
Since this is a triangular matrix, we immediately spot the eigenvalues, namely $\lambda_1 = \cosh^{-2} z$ of multiplicity $2$, and $\lambda_2 = -\cosh^{-2} z$ of multiplicity $1$.

It should be expected that there are only two distinct eigenvalues, since there can only be two principal curvatures, and the result also agrees with the fact that the eigenvalues of the differential $\mathrm dN_p$ turn out to be $\pm \cosh^{-2} u$ when computed in the $(u,v)$ coordinates that I mentioned in the first paragraph.

The eigenvector corresponding to $\lambda_2$ is $(0,0,1),$ which is expected since the meridians of the catenoid are clearly lines of curvature. However, assuming that I did everything correctly, the eigenspace corresponding to $\lambda_1$ is two-dimensional, and spanned by
$$ (1, 0, -x\tanh z) \quad \text{and} \quad (0,1,-y\tanh z), $$
which, as far as I can see, does not agree with the fact that there should only be two principal directions.

How am I to interpret this?

Comment: You’re examining the eigenvalues of a $3\times3$ matrix instead of the two-dimensional shape operator. It’s not terribly surprising that one of the eigenspaces turned out to be two-dimensional.

Comment: But I would expect that both of the eigenspaces would be collapsed to a single dimension, under the restriction of $S$ being a surface. I would also imagine that it should be possible to retrieve the correct principal directions from the eigenvectors of the $3 \times 3$ matrix.

Comment: Why would you expect that? You’ve only restricted where $N$ and hence $dN$ are being evaluated. That doesn’t force its eigenvectors onto the tangent plane. The fact that you got a _constant_ eigenvector for one of the curvatures should make you suspicious: the principal directions should always be orthogonal to the unit normal, but $(0,0,1)$ _never_ is.

Comment: Huh, when you put it that way, one really shouldn't expect it. Thanks for helping me to see this! Feel free to post your comments as an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: I think your approach can be salvaged, at least for a surface of revolution like this one. It’s just going to take a bit more work to extract the principal directions. (I think you need to be looking at the _left_ eigenvectors of $dN$ as you have it here, too.)

Comment: @amd Well, I might try it again some day. For now I think it's best if I stick with the parametrization approach, since it seems to be much simpler and quicker. Thanks again!

Comment: @amd Now that you said it, I can't stop thinking about it. Why the left eigenvectors?